# Angular: How to use *ngFor with an array which has a dynamic name?

Tags: angular

I have some arrays dynamically named sub_0, sub_1, sub_2 etc.
I want to use them with *ngFor but I could not find a way to call them. Not sure if there is a way to do it.

i is a dynamic number, I tried

```
<a class="link" href="#" *ngFor="let sub of sub_+i" > </a>
<a class="link" href="#" *ngFor="let sub of sub_+{{i}}" > </a>
<a class="link" href="#" *ngFor="let sub of sub_$i" > </a>
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: How do you get these dynamic arrays on typescript side? If you show this, we can solve your problem.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL like this['sub_' + i] = value

Comment: So did you try let sub of  ['sub_' + i]?

Comment: What is `i`?, is it from another greater `ngFor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be the same as you use in TS code:

```
*ngFor="let sub of this['sub_' + i]">
```

Comment: yes, worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to handle dynamic logic in the typescript side.

```
// component.ts
const N = 10;
const arrays = Array.from(Array(N).keys()).map(i => `sub_${i}`);

// component.html
<ng-container *ngFor="let array of arrays">
  <a class="link" href="#" *ngFor="let sub of array" > </a>
</ng-container>
```